# Easy way via some attribute to tell JSON deserializer to just stringify json?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, json.net

Example Client JSON:

```
{
   Foo: "Hello!"
   Bar: {
      a: 1,
      b: 2
   }  
}
```

```
public class Foobar
{
  public string Foo {get; set;}
  /*[This will come in as a JSON object to the deserializer - just "flatten it" and return the JSON as a string] */
  public string Bar {get; set;
}
```

Expected Pseudo-Result:

```
Foobar.Foo = "Hello!"
Foobar.Bar = "{a:1, b:2}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JRaw` type.

```cs
class Foobar
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }

    public JRaw Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Example usage:

```cs
var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foobar>(yourJsonString);
var bar = res.Bar.Value.ToString(); // {"a":1,"b":2}
```

Note that `JRaw.Value` is of type `object`, so the `.ToString()` is needed, or, you can cast instead.